# Eclipse | Trouble with "loading xml schemas" window

Tags: xml, eclipse

I am troubled with the "loading xml schema" window, whenever I open a XSD file.
The trouble is that Eclipse takes 5mins to fetch the XSD defnitions (in vain) from the web since that I am behind the firewall and I have not set eclipse with Proxy settings.
Screenshot: http://img121.imageshack.us/i/clipuh.png

Is there anyway that I can stop the window from appearing or at least do it in the background.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can open schema files in XML editor (Open With|XML Editor from context menu).